# SSJS is not executed on xPage

Tags: javascript, xpages

I met some strange problem. A page button does not execute SSJS when it's clicked first time after page load. But does work when you click it again. I found it especially when you clear browser cache.

1. Try to clear Chrome cache (Ctrl+Shift+Del. Clear everything).
2. Restart Chrome.
3. Try to load this page TEST.xsp. First pass server login page.
4. Click 'My Button'. It doesn't do anything. It's supposed to e.g. redirect to same page with a new parameter e.g. param1=true (sure it should do nothing, but just add param1=true to the URL)
5. Click it again. It does work

What could cause this behavior? It can be any SSJS not exactly context.redirectToPage. But it works only when you click button second time. Same problem found on FF but it does work in IE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:button id="button1" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        value="My Button" title="My Button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler10">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.redirectToPage("TEST.xsp?param1=true");}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Here is my app configuration options:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that what you actually intend? You loose the context. Why not just switch to edit mode?

Comment: no.. it was jut an example so you can easy see it doesn't work. Any other code doesn't work

Comment: I have no problems with your example XPage. It redirects on first click of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does help when you put it into afterPageLoad event.

```
if(!sessionScope.APP_LOADED){
    sessionScope.put("APP_LOADED", true);
    context.reloadPage();
}else if(sessionScope.APP_LOADED==false){
    sessionScope.put("APP_LOADED", true);
    context.reloadPage();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the following parameter, then it should work as expected:

[image]

Comment: it's not the problem of redirect. it was jut an example so you can easy see it doesn't work. Any other code doesn't work. And btw, this option enabled in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem. I had to add an OnClientLoad action, with nothing in it. Why exactly I don't know.

Comment: Ok. .was it CSJS or SSJS action? If SSJS what was Server Option?
Anyway I'll try. Thank you

Comment: It needs some server-side activity, but only the bare minimum. No full or partial refresh.